# how to use a function in the form in a class c#

Tags: c#, function, class, label

im trying to get a function thats in a form to work in a class.

```
public void Say(string Text)
    {
        lalSay.Text = Text;
    }
```

this is the code in the form.

```
Say("Darn i dont have" + ItemCost + "Bits.");
                          //^this is a string in my program
```

and this is in the class.

I just cant find whats wrong??

it wont let me use the function in the class.

Comment: If Say() is in the Form, a different Class won't have any idea what Say() is.  To use Say() from within the Class would require you to pass a Reference to the Form into the class so you can call Say() against that instance of the Form.  An alternative would be to make the Class raise a Custom Event that the Form listens for.  Then when that event is received the Form can call Say() directly with the requested string.

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Answer (score 2):

```
Say(Darn i dont have" + ItemCost + "Bits.);
```

Your argument is not a string. Use it like this

```
Say("Darn i dont have" + ItemCost + "Bits.");
//   ^ String one         ^ variable  ^ string two
```

code like this `"some text"` is treated as a string.

Comment: @MahchinLizard: then you should specify what the problem is.

Comment: @MahchinLizard Could it be that you are not putting a `ToString()` on `ItemCost`?  What type is `ItemCost`?

Comment: its a string in the program/game.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great lack of detail to your question, but perhaps this is a place to start.

If you are unable to "use the function in the class", are you consuming it like this?

```
public class Form1:Form{
    public void Say(string Text)
    {
        lalSay.Text = Text;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass{
    public void ConsumingMethod()
    {
        var say = new Form1();
        say.Say("Darn i dont have" + ItemCost + "Bits.");
    }   
}
```

EDIT:
Consuming a method from a Form class in another class is bad code.  You should have your business logic in its own class and have the GUI layers consume it.  Moving your `Say` method to a supporting class is a better idea that calling it from within your Form from another class.

Comment: im trying to get a function thats in a form to work in a class.

Comment: @MahchinLizard Let me know if those edits make sense.